# Is there a pythonic way to add an enumerating column while exploding a list column in pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, enumeration

Consider the following `DataFrame`:

```py
>>> df = pd.DataFrame({'A': [1,2,3], 'B':['abc', 'def', 'ghi']}).apply({'A':int, 'B':list})
>>> df
   A          B
0  1  [a, b, c]
1  2  [d, e, f]
2  3  [g, h, I]
```

This is one way to get the desired result:

```py
>>> df['B'] = df['B'].apply(enumerate).apply(list)
>>> df = df.explode('B', ignore_index=True)
>>> df['B'] = pd.Series(df['B'], index=['B1', 'B2'])})
>>> df.droplevel(0, axis=1)
   A  B1 B2
0  1   0  a
1  1   1  b
2  1   2  c
3  2   0  d
4  2   1  e
5  2   2  f
6  3   0  g
7  3   1  h
8  3   2  i
```

Is there a neater way?

Answer (score 3):

A groupby on the index is an option:

```py
df.explode('B').assign(
  B1 = lambda df: df.groupby(level=0).cumcount())

   A  B  B1
0  1  a   0
0  1  b   1
0  1  c   2
1  2  d   0
1  2  e   1
1  2  f   2
2  3  g   0
2  3  h   1
2  3  i   2
```

you can always reset the index, if you have no use for it:

```py
df.explode('B').assign(
  B1 = lambda df: df.groupby(level=0).cumcount()).reset_index(drop=True)

   A  B  B1
0  1  a   0
1  1  b   1
2  1  c   2
3  2  d   0
4  2  e   1
5  2  f   2
6  3  g   0
7  3  h   1
8  3  i   2
```

Since `pandas` version `1.3.0` you can use multiple columns with `explode` out of the box:

```py
df.assign(
  B1 = df.B.apply(len).apply(range)).explode(['B', 'B1'], ignore_index = True))

   A  B B1
0  1  a  0
1  1  b  1
2  1  c  2
3  2  d  0
4  2  e  1
5  2  f  2
6  3  g  0
7  3  h  1
8  3  i  2
```

I think a faster option would be to run the reshaping outside Pandas, and then rejoin back to the dataframe (of course only tests can affirm/deny this):

```py
from itertools import chain
# you can use np.concatenate instead
# np.concatenate(df.B)
flattened = chain.from_iterable(df.B)
index = df.index.repeat([*map(len, df.B)])
flattened = pd.Series(flattened, index, name = 'B1')
(pd.concat([df.A, flattened], axis=1)
  .assign(B2 = lambda df: df.groupby(level=0).cumcount())
)

   A B1  B2
0  1  a   0
0  1  b   1
0  1  c   2
1  2  d   0
1  2  e   1
1  2  f   2
2  3  g   0
2  3  h   1
2  3  i   2
```

Comment: This does indeed look neat! How does it compare computationally, I have to apply it to a large volume of nested lists so efficiency is also a consideration. Also - does this guarantee the "original order" in the B1 column?

Comment: speed wise, I'll do the reshaping outside of Pandas, within python (wer are dealing with lists here, there is not computational advantage using it with Pandas, I might be wrong though)

Comment: I think the `str` would only work if the `B` column was of type `str` while it's actually of type `list` (that's just how I constructed the toy example). Regardless, the last solution seems to be neater even if we can't apply `len` directly

Comment: apparently the pd.Series.str.len option supports lists/tuples/ ...

Comment: Actually the last snippet doesn't work for me - it breaks on the `explode` application: `ValueError: column must be a scalar` Seems like a single column is expected, not a list

Comment: what version are you on? I am on pandas 1.3

Comment: I have `1.2.4` installed

Comment: the list option was added in 1.3 I believe. you probably have to try the other snippets, or update to the latest pandas version