# New dataframe of all non-NaN pairs of elements between two columns in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

Trying to go from a DataFrame where each row is a source entity and columns are the type of relations between one or more entities like this:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

i = [['a', np.nan, np.nan, ['d', 'e']],
     ['b', 'f', np.nan, np.nan],
     ['c', np.nan, 'g', 'h']]
inputs = pd.DataFrame(i, columns=['source', 'mom', 'dad', 'sibling'])
```

To one where each row includes a source's unique target entity and relation type in separate columns:

```
o = [['a', 'd', 'sibling'],
     ['a', 'e', 'sibling'],
     ['b', 'f', 'mom'],
     ['c', 'g', 'dad'],
     ['c', 'h', 'sib']]
outputs = pd.DataFrame(o)
```

I've looked at pandas functionality including `stack()` and `explode()` but can't figure out how to implement a pandas-native solution. Any suggestions on how to do this efficiently?

Comment: ``inputs.explode('sibling').melt('source').dropna()``

Comment: Ah, melt was the thing I needed. Is there any way to account for when the lists are uneven? I'm trying to inputs.explode(['mom','dad',''sibling']) but this won't work because some of the lists are not all of the same length. Thanks @sammywemmy!

Comment: that will be tricky. you are better off working within python before going back to Pandas. see if the solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69795129/7175713) helps

Comment: So I think if I chain explode after melt, I should be good to go: inputs.melt('source',var_name="relationship").dropna().explode('value')

Comment: you can post your solution, and mark it as well. It will be helpful to me and others

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Per @sammywemmy , melt and explode should do the trick:

```
inputs.melt("source", var_name="relationship").dropna().explode('value')
```